# How to get selection appearance like listview for textview in android

Tags: android

I have a textview and some text is present inside of it. Now if i tap on textview, i want section appearance like listview. when i press on the text, it should show me selection appearance, how to do?

Answer (score 2):

use selector [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```