# Facebook style button in Android (selector.xml)

Tags: android, facebook, layout, button

Right now, I'm coding an OAuth/Facebook login in my app, and I'd like to add a native button (not a ImageButton with some kind of image on it as src/bg) with the Facebook color and font styles. Does anyone knows the combination of settings to create a **selector** xml file that appears like facebook styles?
I know that it sounds to be lazy from my part... but I'm tired on trying to reach the correct settings by experimenting through empirical trial-and-error. So, I hope that someone already knows this settings. It should be something like the bellow image:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are the "facebook styles" can you post a picture or elaborate some more on what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Ru looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11309671/1012284

Comment: Hi Tim. I've updated the question with an image. The style uses mainly blue and white colors. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Hi Kumar. Yes, I want to use this type of code within a selector. This I already knows how to do. What I'm seeking is the combination of RGB that I should put in the values of these fields to reach a result similar to a facebook stylized button. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @mthama I think for RGB values you can use Photoshop!